# Autowrapper not returning response object when setting status code

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using auto wrapper in asp.net core and if for a particular id there is no data returned I want to return 204 (NoContent)

```
   [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAccountByAccountNumber/{accountNumber}")]
    public async Task<ApiResponse> GetAccountByAccountNumber(string accountNumber)
    {

        var account = await _accountsService.GetAccountByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
        if (account == null)
            return new ApiResponse("Account with accountnumber {accountNumber} does nto exists", 204);
        return new ApiResponse("Account By Number Returned", account);

    }
```

when I give a call this api i get Error aborted

[image]

where as I am expecting usual AutoWrappers response with status code and stuff.

in program.cs

```
    app.UseApiResponseAndExceptionWrapper(new AutoWrapperOptions
{
    EnableResponseLogging = true,
    EnableExceptionLogging = true,
    LogRequestDataOnException = true
});
```

am i missing something?

**Update**
There is nothing wrong in the DB call. is it expected to return null and is returning null. But when I return Api response I get aborted

[image]

in the app insights i see

> Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written

**Update 2**
If I return 200 instead of 204 it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a problem with using Autowrapper. I test to create asp.net core3.1 project, using AutoWrapper.Core -Version 4.5.0. Everything works fine.

I think the problem is related to `await _accountsService.GetAccountByAccountNumber(accountNumber);`,
this line of code.

You can use `CancellationToken` to check it. For more details, please below blog.

[Handling aborted requests in ASP.NET Core](https://www.meziantou.net/handling-aborted-requests-in-asp-net-core.htm)

Comment: looks like there is nothing wrong in the DB call. check the update

Comment: @RaasMasood What version of AutoWrapper.Core are you using? [And I can't reproduce the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XunF.png), so I need more details.

Comment: i am using AutoWrapper.core 4.5.0

Comment: i had to remove "UseApiResponseAndExceptionWrapper" to make it to work. i was able to reproduce it in a new project with just an api returning Apiresponse 204 and "UseApiResponseAndExceptionWrapper". got same error. 
i am using this line just before app.Run();